# Do not show first option in SELECT

Tags: html

Is it possible to not show the first option as selected in a `<select>`, without adding a blank option?

```
        <select id="location" name="location" class="form-control">
          <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="France">France</option>
          <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
          <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
          <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
          <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
          <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
          <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="United States">United States</option>
        </select>
```

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1):

No.

Typically you might add something like:

```
<option value="0">Please select a country</option>
```

Then in your JS check if it's got a value of 0 before form submit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible as described in here: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Example: [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected)